# Virus Mortality Selection

Tags: microbiology, virology

This question is related to the recent Wuhan outbreak. Currently, mortality rate for the virus is somewhere around 2-3%. This is much lower than say, SARS (9.5%) and MERS (34.5%).

As a thought experiment, the main cause of death of the above viruses tends to be pneumonia (direct and secondary). If pneumonia leads to a higher rate of infection, then (indirectly) would such a virus would become much more deadly over time?

Do viruses such as the coronavirus self-select for higher rates of mortality, e.g. by leading to pneumonia, thus causing more phlegm and coughing?

Related to the above, how quickly can such mutations arise?

Sources would be really appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE! Please take the [tour] and then go through the help pages starting with [Ask] questions effectively on this site and [edit] your question accordingly. In particular note that speculative questions (i.e. thought experiments) are **not** appropriate for this site. ——— We also encourage you to do some research on your own and then, informed by what you have learned, ask any questions you still have (ideally with references to reliable sources). Thanks! 

Comment: Stack Exchange Biology does not have the remit or expertise to answer most questions about coronaviruses relating to the recent 2019-nCoV outbreak. [A list of what are regarded as reputable external sources of such information](https://biology.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4035/information-about-coronaviruses/4036#4036) has been posted on Biology Meta. Please consult that.